# WPF: How can I wrap the items in a ItemsControl in another Template?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, datatemplate

I have an `ItemsControl` that contains items that each has its own `DataTemplate`. Each `ViewModel` class in the ItemsSource derives from a common ancestor that has a `Header` property.

I want to wrap each item in a `Expander` control, but my problem is that I don't know how to 'carry over' each 'DataTemplate' to the DataContext of the expading part of the Expander.

In code, my problem looks like this:

VieModels:

```
public class VM { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class VM1 : VM { public string Description { get; set; } }
public class VM2 : VM { public string Sakkie { get; set; } }
```

Items property on the code-behind (because it's simple for the purpose of this question)

```
    public IEnumerable<VM> Items
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new VM1() { Name = "First VM1", Description = "First VM1 Description" };
            yield return new VM2() { Name = "Vm2, nr2", Sakkie = "sakkie sakkie boeredans" } ;
            yield break;
        }
    }
```

The XAML of the window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
        <local:VM1UC />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
        <local:VM2UC />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
            <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="LightCoral" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
```

It looks like this, which is suprising, but understandable:

[alt text http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/6937/itemscontrol.png](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/6937/itemscontrol.png)

I am actually expecting the custom UserControls to show up in the expanded sections...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the `DataContext`, you should set the `Content`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

This will ensure the appropriate `DataTemplate` is resolved based on the type of the `Content`.

Comment: Wow! Perfect solution, thanks! (Where's the upvote twice button?)